# Error on update from 2.3 to 2.8 and 2.7?

Tags: 8, commerce

I'm using drupal commerce 2.3 and want to update to commerce 2.8.

I just copied the files to the new folder and get the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'CommerceGuys\Addressing\AddressFormat\FieldOverride' not found in C:\www\crypto-excel\modules\contrib\commerce\modules\store\src\Entity\Store.php:272
Stack trace:
#0 C:\www\crypto-excel\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityFieldManager.php(206): Drupal\commerce_store\Entity\Store::baseFieldDefinitions(Object(Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityType))
#1 C:\www\crypto-excel\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityFieldManager.php(171): Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityFieldManager->buildBaseFieldDefinitions('commerce_store')
#2 C:\www\crypto-excel\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityManager.php(182): Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityFieldManager->getBaseFieldDefinitions('commerce_store')
#3 C:\www\crypto-excel\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldType\EntityReferenceItem.php(72): Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityManager->getBaseFieldDefinitions('commerce_store')
#4 C:\www\crypto-excel\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldType\EntityReferenceItem.php(118): Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldType\EntityReferenc in C:\www\crypto-excel\modules\contrib\commerce\modules\store\src\Entity\Store.php on line 272

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'CommerceGuys\Addressing\AddressFormat\FieldOverride' not found in C:\www\crypto-excel\modules\contrib\commerce\modules\store\src\Entity\Store.php:272
Stack trace:
#0 C:\www\crypto-excel\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityFieldManager.php(206): Drupal\commerce_store\Entity\Store::baseFieldDefinitions(Object(Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityType))
#1 C:\www\crypto-excel\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityFieldManager.php(171): Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityFieldManager->buildBaseFieldDefinitions('commerce_store')
#2 C:\www\crypto-excel\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityManager.php(182): Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityFieldManager->getBaseFieldDefinitions('commerce_store')
#3 C:\www\crypto-excel\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldType\EntityReferenceItem.php(72): Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityManager->getBaseFieldDefinitions('commerce_store')
#4 C:\www\crypto-excel\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldType\EntityReferenceItem.php(118): Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldType\EntityReferenc in C:\www\crypto-excel\modules\contrib\commerce\modules\store\src\Entity\Store.php on line 272
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.                                           [31;40m[1m[error][0m
Error: Uncaught Error: Class 'CommerceGuys\Addressing\AddressFormat\FieldOverride' not found in
C:\www\crypto-excel\modules\contrib\commerce\modules\store\src\Entity\Store.php:272
Stack trace:
#0 C:\www\crypto-excel\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityFieldManager.php(206):
Drupal\commerce_store\Entity\Store::baseFieldDefinitions(Object(Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityType))
#1 C:\www\crypto-excel\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityFieldManager.php(171):
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityFieldManager->buildBaseFieldDefinitions('commerce_store')
#2 C:\www\crypto-excel\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityManager.php(182):
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityFieldManager->getBaseFieldDefinitions('commerce_store')
#3 C:\www\crypto-excel\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldType\EntityReferenceItem.php(72):
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityManager->getBaseFieldDefinitions('commerce_store')
#4 C:\www\crypto-excel\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldType\EntityReferenceItem.php(118):
Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldType\EntityReferenc in
C:\www\crypto-excel\modules\contrib\commerce\modules\store\src\Entity\Store.php, line 272
```

But when I go to :
 C:\www\crypto-excel\modules\contrib\commerce\modules\store\src\Entity\Store.php

This file is just there.

I tried the same to goto commerce 2.7, but then same error applies.

Somebody any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

> I just copied the files to the new folder

That's not how to update a Drupal 8 project - you need to use Composer.

Run `composer update` in your project root, and the old version of the address library (commerceguys/addressing), which is causing your current problem, will be upgraded alongside the modules.

Comment: As Clive said. Also, we have official docs for this: https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/install-update/updating